# Broken DVD drive sata port

Tags: sata

I have a blue ray DVD drive, which uses sata to connect it to the mobo. On the DVD drive, contacts in the sata port broke off into the sata cable and now the drive has a few pins where I should plug the sata into. Is it possible to take a sata and sata power port from another hard drive/DVD drive and put it in my DVD drive?

Comment: If you don't have additional SATA ports then you really don't have any choices but to replace the motherboard itself or the device depending which connector specifically failed (you didn't make this clear).

Comment: " Is it possible to take a sata and sata power port from another hard drive/DVD drive and put it in my DVD drive?" This is indeed possible but, I will be honest, if you asking if its possible then you unlikely have the technical or soldering skills to do so.

Comment: Doubt you can do that, better to buy a new bluray drive.

Comment: Hi Brandon, please remove *Solved. Thanks guys* from your question. You will be able to accept the answer you found helpful, this will indicate that the question is solved. (May take some hours until you are able to do)

Answer (score 3):

**Is it possible?**

Sure, after all, the pins are simply metal contacts that need to have a metal contact to your motherboard in order to work. There are even some [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3oezp97xqdU) on people doing something similar.

**Should you?**

Depending on what you consider a worthwhile risk. Let's say you accidentally short a pin, best case scenario is your BluRay drive doesn't work as expected and disappears from your machine, or your machine temporarily shuts off.

Worst case scenario? Who knows? Damage to the drive, blown PSU, damaged SATA controller, damage to the motherboard south bridge? Fire? Unlikely, but nothing is impossible when dealing with a short.

For the sake of about $40 USD, just get yourself a new drive without any damage and have the peace of mind that everything is in full working order.

Comment: The video you linked is exactly what happened, thank you for that! I looked around and I can get the drive for much cheaper than I had previously thought so I'll just end up buying a new one to be safe. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, depends how your skills de/soldering surface mounted devices. And is it really worth x hours of time when a new drive could be 'cheaper' route.